# Bash: delete from cursor till end of line with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: command-line, bash

Consider the following bash prompt, where `^` denotes the prompt location:

```
$ git commit -am "[bug 123456] Do this and that with the bug"
                               ^
```

Suppose that I want to commit again to the same bug, with a different commit message. Is there a way to delete the text from the cursor position till the end of line?

Answer (score 197, accepted):

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>K</kbd> to delete from the cursor to the end of the line.

Use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>U</kbd> to delete from the cursor to the beginning of the line.

Comment: What is the key combination to put?

Comment: @ShooShoSha, Try Shift + Insert

Comment: what are the meanings of K and U, I can not recall this next week if I donot know the meanings, how to remember them?

Comment: @hylepo Dunno but my mnemonic is `Brexit - the UK leaves Europe` - U deletes to the beginning and K to the end.

Answer (score 55):

It depends on whether you are using vi(`set -o vi`) or emacs(`set -o emacs`) editing mode within your shell.

By default, your shell generally defaults to emacs editing mode.

- In emacs mode, deleting to the end of the line can be accomplished by using the command <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>k</kbd>.
- If, however, you happen to be using vi editing mode in your command shell, the same result can be accomplished by typing <kbd>Esc</kbd>(which will place you in command mode) followed by <kbd>d</kbd>-<kbd>$</kbd>(if you want to delete the entire line, enter <kbd>dd</kbd>).

If you are uncertain as to which editing mode that you are currently using in your shell, enter the command `set -o` from the command line and you will be able to determine which editing mode that you are currently using:

```
set -o
...snip...
emacs           on
...snip...
vi              off
```

To switch your command-line editing mode, simply type either:

```
set -o vi
```

or

```
set -o emacs
```

Comment: Thanks. It seems that I'm using vi, so `CTRL`+`K` does the trick.

Comment: If you want a mnemonic, the `K` stands for kill (the line starting from cursor position).

Comment: In vi command mode, `D` works the same as `d$`

Comment: +1 for actually writing the **right** answer and explaining that shellopts may change it.

Comment: >> Thanks. It seems that I'm using vi, so CTRL+K does the trick. – Adam Matan Adam, then that's emacs-mode you're in, not vi.

Comment: In Kubuntu oneiric (konsole), Ctrl+K and ESC Shift+D both work. ESC d deletes some of the line (maybe up to a ';'). (Typing a $ after that just sends the $ to the console.) I've been trying to figure out how to do that for quite awhile. Thanks!

Comment: using `set -o` in zsh shell returns emacs and vi are set to off. However, `Ctrl`+`k` works.

Answer (score 5):

In case you're only familiar with one of Zsh and Bash, here are the equivalent key bindings you (may) need:

## bash

```
bind '"\C-k"':kill-line
```

## zsh

```
bindkey "\C-k"      vi-kill-eol
```

---

**Other relevant information**

To get a list of key bindings:

```
# bash
bind -p

# zsh
bindkey
```

Comment: I'm confused. For Bash, shouldn't it be `"^k"`  for Control+K ?

Comment: Sorry, that is my personal binding. I would have put the default binding but was not comfortable with bash syntax. Since you've mentioned what it should be I've taken your word for it and edited my post.

Comment: Oh, OK. I'm not familiar with it myself, but just checked and it should be `"\C-k"`